# Dozer Mapping: Mapping via XML vs Mapping via API. Which one performs faster?

Tags: java, dozer

In my project, i'm using dozer mapping via XML. But my project teams asking me to use Mapping via API. They claim that mapping via API will be faster than XML , as mapping via api is compiled code already.

Kindly help me understand whether this mapping via API is really faster than mapping via XML.

Answer (score 2):

I think your team may be missing the point. Remember that all you are doing when you are supplying either XML or API mapping to Dozer is *configuring* it. You're not actually mapping anything at config time, and configuration usually only happens once at application startup.

Once configured, both approaches use the same reflection based engine to do the grunt work of the actual mapping using a call like this (amongst other options):

```
DestinationObject destObject = mapper.map(sourceObject, DestinationObject.class);
```

If you're *really* concerned about mapping performance; then map manually with gets/sets.